# Pass data in redirect() - Typo3

Tags: php, model-view-controller, typo3, extbase

I have a form after validation if any error occur the page will redirected to the edit itself with an error message.How to pass previous data and an error message  through redirect() in typo3 ?

```
$this->redirect($action_name,$controllername, $extensionName, array('data',$data));
```

Is it right?

my action name is `'edit'` But it is redirect to `'list'` .Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Just to make sure, what did you set $action_name to 'edit'? The issue might be that the action name could not be resolved and then the default action is called. Is listAction your default action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The arguments to pass to the redirect-target have to be given as associative array. The key is the argument name (as in the actions method header, without the `$`), the value is the argument value. Looks like this:

```
$this->redirect(
    $action_name,
    $controllername,
    $extensionName,
    [
        'data' => $data
    ]
);
```

How exactly `$data` is encoded in the URL depends on its type. Persistent objects are encoded as their ID, scalars are encoded as simple strings. How they arrive in the other action depends on that actions typehints and `@param` annotations.

To redirect to the same controller or extension, you can pass `$controllerName`and `$extensionName` as `null`.

Comment: You can also pass the object itself rather than just the Uid.

Comment: +1 @Jost and one more parameter you can pass is pageUid where your FE plugin configured: $this->redirect($action_name,$controllername,$extensionName,array('data'=>'arguments'),$pageUid);

Answer (score 3):

The arguments are passed as an array with key value pairs, where the key is the parameter name. This assumes that your target action has a parameter named "data".
    `$this->redirect($action_name,$controllername, $extensionName, array('data' =>$data));`

Answer (score 1):

Jost's answer is sufficient to your question but if you want to know more:

1. your controller action should be editAction()
2. you should register your action/controller in ext_localconf.php
3. you have to allow your action in plugin Flexform configuration [if more actions or switchableControllerActions]
4. clear install tool cache sometimes create magik ;)

Reference: [extBase Fluid Book](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/b-ExtbaseReference/Index.html#most-important-api-methods-of-action-controller)