# Typo3 8.7: Passing data between actions via redirect() doesn't work

Tags: php, typo3-8.7.x

I'm trying to redirect from one Action (`createAction()`) to another Action (`editAction()`) inside the same Controller) and pass an Model object as an array.

Like this:

```
$this->redirect('edit', 'Checklist', NULL, array('checklist' => $newChecklist));
```

I have used all the information given in [Pass data in redirect() - Typo3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38299136/pass-data-in-redirect-typo3) but in the Action I'm passing my object to, the all attributes of the object are empty (NULL or empty Strings).

Here the full Controller code regarding the two actions.

```
     /**
         * action create
         *
         * @param \bli\bla\Domain\Model\Checklist $newChecklist
         * @return void
         */
        public function createAction(\bli\bla\Domain\Model\Checklist $newChecklist) {

            if (TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') {
                $this->addFlashMessage('', \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('flash-message-create-sucessfull', $this->extensionName), \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::OK);

                $this->checklistRepository->add($newChecklist);

                $persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager');
                $persistenceManager->persistAll();
                /*$newChecklist is full at this point*/
                $this->redirect('edit', 'Checklist', NULL, array('checklist' => $newChecklist));
            } else {
                if ($this->checkLogin()) {
                    $this->addFlashMessage('', \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\LocalizationUtility::translate('flash-message-create-sucessfull', $this->extensionName), \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::OK);

                    $this->checklistRepository->add($newChecklist);

                    $persistenceManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Persistence\\Generic\\PersistenceManager');
                    $persistenceManager->persistAll();
                    $this->redirect('edit', 'Checklist', NULL, array('checklist' => $newChecklist));
                } else {
                    $this->redirect('notLoggedIn', 'Checklist', NULL, array());
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * action edit
         *
         * @param \bli\bla\Domain\Model\Checklist $checklist
         * @ignorevalidation $checklist
         * @return void
         */
        public function editAction(\bli\bla\Model\Checklist $checklist) {
            /*AT THIS POINT, $checklist is empty (NULL or Empty Strings)*/

if (TYPO3_MODE == 'BE') {
                //clear cache
                $this->cacheService->clearPageCache(intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id));

                $this->view->assign('checklist', $checklist);

                $this->view->assign('chapters', $checklist->getChapter()->toArray());
            } else {
                if ($this->checkLogin()) {
                    //clear cache
                    $this->cacheService->clearPageCache(intval($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id));

                    $this->view->assign('scopeTypes', $this->scopeTypeRepository->findAll());
                    $this->view->assign('checklist', $checklist);
                    $this->view->assign('chapters', $checklist->getChapter()->toArray());
                } else {
                    $this->redirect('notLoggedIn', 'Checklist', NULL, array());
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't find any errors in my code. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can try to pass only the uid instead the whole object.

Comment: This error happenend due to false TCA configuration in my localconf. Therefore there were problems regarding persistence in my extension. But thank you anyways!